# How do I use the "Foam" Attachment on a "cheap" pressure washer?

Tags: cleaning, pressure-washer

I picked up a low cost, battery powered pressure washer from aliexpress - it has a pipe meant to be put into a bucket (for washing cars), and blasts water either in a highish pressure stream, or in a straight spray fairly effectively. It also has a "foam" attachment as pictured which I can't quite suss out the function of

[image]

Its a simple container with a single tube leading in. I've tested it with "pure" and watered down soap, and with and without the 'main' water feed attached. It sprays water, with the *slightest* tease of soapy water at best with water, and nothing without water.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'd love to know how I could get this to work (or if there's fundamentally something wrong here).

Comment: Depending on the soap/detergent used, foam might not be that great.  Usually they say foam for spraying soap plus water onto stuff.  What does the instructions say?  You did read them, didn't you?

Comment: Didn't come with instructions.

Comment: Usually they really soap dispensers and work by the water sucking the soap out of the container.  Some work better than others.  If soap is less at end of the job, it is working.

Comment: You probably need a very 'runny' soap solution for that to work. Anything think & 'syrupy' like dish detergent is not going to get sucked up that siphon pipe well enough.

Comment: Tried both runny soap and syrupy soap. Didn't actually try car shampoo, since I was washing floors...

Comment: Hard to tell from the photos, but doesn't it go on *instead* of the wand, rather than on the end of it. Overall the device looks like a hokey copy of a Spear & Jackson I have… https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSb4m.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9b7T.jpg ['scuse the mess, just laid them out on the junk room floor ;)

Comment: Ah no, the wand has a sort of quick disconnect that works with the nozzles and the sprayer on one end, and a screw on connection on the other.